# Turn off pretty listing in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, macros, add-in

I have a macro/addin where I need to disable the Vb.Net **pretty listing** temporary.

[image: VB Pretty listing option]

Tried to record a macro but it only shows that I opened the options dialog.

Also tried

```
Dim props As EnvDTE.Properties = DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "Basic")
```

but the props collection does not contain any of the options under VB Specific.
(The options from General and Tabs are int the collection)

Comment: Why do you think you need to turn it off *temporarily*? If you're inserting code that doesn't match the formatting, the slightest nudge afterwards will cause it to reformat anyway.

Comment: Maybe he want to turn it off for one project, and turn on for another?

Comment: I got a macro that aligns the selected text on punctuations so I can use block selection/edit to modify it. The text is supposed to be reformatted again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a listing of options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165642%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

In my case it is

```
Dim prettyListingProperty = DTE.Properties("TextEditor", "Basic-Specific").Item("PrettyListing")
```