# Aligning text under Visual Studio code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, code-organization

How to align/indent text under `Visual Studio 2012`, to achieve the below:

Original code

```
SomeThing = A + B + C
SomeLongerThing = D + E + F
```

Organized code

```
SomeThing          = A + B + C
SomeLongerThing    = D + E + F
```

If I try to hit `Tab` button on keyboard to add indentation, Visual Studio automatically squeezes the code back to the orignial position (as shown in the Original code above).

Comment: Which language? When does VS apply the automatic formatting? Is there no whitespace between `E` and `+` and does VS keep it this way?

Comment: VB.NET. Formatting is applied when exiting the row (going to another row with arrow or enter). Missing whitespace was a typo (fixed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of the pretty listing feature of VS. See Tools -> Options ... -> Text Editor -> Basic -> VB Specific -> Checkbox "Pretty listing (reformatting) of code".

Related: [Turn off pretty listing in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152999/turn-off-pretty-listing-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Nice. And while turning this off, looks like I can hit Ctrl + K + F on any selected text to "pretty format" that quickly.

Comment: why would anyone turn such a useful feature off? Is that some form of masochism?