# Visual Studio 2015 Keep Turning Off the Pretty listing (reformatting) of code Option for VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

For some strange reasons it un-checks the Pretty listing (reformatting) of code option from time to time.

I have to keep turning it back on to keep my code "pretty" :-)

This has never happened on VS2013.

Just wondering does anyone have the same issue?

Comment: It is happening to me too. It seems like it happens after I get an error while comparing file versions during a Code Review.

Comment: Do you use Resharper? I'm not sure if Visual Studio is doing it or Resharper.

Comment: That's a good point. I turned re-sharper off a few days ago due to performance issues and I haven't got this problem after that. If it doesn't happen for another week I think we can probably conclude this is a re-sharper related issue. Will keep an eye on this.

Comment: I don't use resharper, though I do use CodeRush, and I keep getting the same problem as well. I raised an issue for it during the time I was using the release candidate, but never saw anything come of it

Comment: FYI. I haven't got this issue for a couple of weeks now. The only thing I did is uninstall re-sharper. There was also a few windows 10 updates but I doubt thats going to affect VS2015.

Comment: FWIW this used to happen in VS2008 as well, but only after installing an addon called the Source Outliner Power Toy (https://sourcecodeoutliner.codeplex.com/). So perhaps the issue is related to something various addons do related to examining code.

Answer (score 9):

While my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35096849/4397397) is a decent workaround, it's now been 10 months since this question was originally asked and it seems like most days Pretty Listing decides to turn itself off, and it's getting more frustrating. So here's another workaround that might lead us to the cause of this bug.

I wrote an extension that periodically checks if Pretty Listing has been turned off. If it has, it turns it back on and shows an alert at the bottom of the screen so we can hopefully work out what caused it to turn off in the first place.

It checks every 30 seconds, but you can lower this if you like (check the description on the extension page).

You can get the extension here: [Pretty Listing Fixer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/47db893a-b50a-4267-8866-9f3fd4ff2dac)

Comment: Nice! After over a year this issue has finally annoyed me enough to find a fix. Out of curiosity, have you noticed it tends to check itself off when VS is lagging and struggling to keep up?  I've always figured it did it for performance reasons and that it was meant to toggle off until performance improved, but that its ability to toggle back on on was broken.

Comment: To be honest, I don't even notice that it gets turned off anymore, because this extension just turns it back on again. :D  But when I was initially investigating how this was occurring, I managed to replicate it by having two instances and making ReSharper do some sort of formatting in one of the instances. At exactly the same time, Pretty Listing would turn off in the other instance. I'm sure theres other ways to cause it too.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem (both with and without ReSharper installed, so that doesn't seem to be the problem). I "sent a frown" to Microsoft about this some time ago but have heard nothing back.

While this isn't a "fix", I have come across a handy workaround. Since "pretty listing" and the "Format Document" command give the same result, all you need to do is run that command.

I found [this extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3ea1c920-69c4-441f-9979-ccc2752dac56?SRC=VSIDE) which automatically runs the Format Document command when you save. Now, even if "pretty listing" does get mysteriously turned off, I still end up with my code being formatted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

This won't solve the problem as such, but there is an example of how to set the Pretty Listing option directly using a macro, here: [Turn off pretty listing in visual studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152999/turn-off-pretty-listing-in-visual-studio)

So you could set up a macro which you can run easily with a hotkey when needed. If that code doesn't work, I recommend the ever-magnificent AutoHotkey (www.autohotkey.com) to do the same thing via a series of keystrokes.